# Transform source code into LaTeX

Tags: java, math, latex, expression, documentation-generation

I frequently come across lots of physics equations implemented in Java and Fortran. In most cases these equations are copied straight from an advanced physics textbook or a publication. The equations in their original form are quite easy to read because they are usually typeset in LaTeX. However, when these equations are translated into code they look like gibberish. Even using short domain-specific variable names [as suggested here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176582/is-there-an-excuse-for-short-variable-names), or breaking down the equation into multiple line doesn't make it look as intuitive as the typeset version.

Is there any tool that can parse a Java/Fortran source file and output it in LaTeX, transforming all mathematical expressions into their LaTeX equivalent. For example,

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2))
```

is transformed into

```
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
```

Just to be clear. I am not looking for solutions that allow LaTeX to be included as a part of comments/javadoc. Because that would only create LaTeX output of my comments and not the expression in the source code.

Comment: Do you need something that would also handle custom functions e.t.c.?

Comment: Custom functions could be kept as is. But I would expect standard methods from the Math class to be supported. Also as a bonus, it would be great if the tool could understand subscript notation in variable names. For example t_out would be translated as 't' subscript 'out'.

Comment: Well, for _this_ specfic example, you coudl use some sort of script to replace `Math.` with a backslash, and a `(`,`)` with their corresponding `{`,`}` all you need to define is `\newcommand{\pow}[2]{#1^{#2}}` and you have LaTeX equivalent output code...

Comment: I agree that works for this example. But in general we would need something that traverses and transforms the syntax tree. And I forgot to mention, another value added feature would be to recognize Greek letters in variable names and produce the LaTeX equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have seen something like you request done with the projectional editor of [jetbrains mps](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/). It used to show arithmetic expressions in source code as latex-like rendered equations. Though I can't remember exactly, where I saw it. Maybe it was [mbeddr](http://mbeddr.wordpress.com/).

However you are more interested in the way from source to latex, so here is my suggestion:
[ATL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl) provides a model-to-model transformation. You could use it to transform your Java expressions to latex expressions. Therefore you need an [EMF model](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) of Java. [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco) already ships with a Java 1.5 model. I don't know of a latex EMF model. To serialize the model to latex sources, you could use [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).

Comment: I found some libraries that do Java AST parsing: [Java Parser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html) , [Eclipse JDT](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html) , and [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/)